# How to see traffic from a country to a page in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I know how to look at the OVERALL traffic to my site by country, but I'm wondering how can I look at the traffic to an individual PAGE from a country?

eg. I want to look at what % of people visiting my shopping cart are coming from the UK.  Are there any standard reports in Google Analytics that can do that?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, they are. In the left-side menu, go to **Content** → **Site Content** → **Pages**. Then, click on the **Secondary dimension** button below the graph and choose **Visitors** → **Country/Territory**.

[image]

You will be presented with the pageviews per page per country.

[image]

Note: this method applies to the new version of Analytics.